# Which way is length and which way is width?

Tags: geometry, terminology

I hear people refer to the dimensions of things as "$2$ by $4$" etc. and I know its length by width, but I can't tell if the length dimension is vertical (up and down) or horizontal (side to side). Does anyone know?

Comment: For a rectangle, I tend to use "length" for the longer side and "width" for the shorter one.

Comment: This seems more like a question on language, than a math one.

Comment: An $m$ by $n$ matrix is $m$ rows by $n$ columns (I've never seen it otherwise).  But most other times it's just ambiguous.

Comment: I think length is vertical and width is horizontal

Comment: In mathematics it does not usually matter how you name the dimensions. In English, I feel, _length_ is usually in the “most important” dimension while _width_ is horizontal and at right-angles to the length. Neither is usually vertical: that is the _height_. The “most important” dimension is often that in which you move or look, or the longest. _Length_ can also apply to time, while _width_ cannot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think "length" and "width" are ambiguous.  I can confirm that native English-speaking college students will sometimes use length=2, width=4, and sometimes use length=4, width=2.  Of course, the area is 8 either way.

When I want to avoid ambiguity, I say Area = (base)x(height) or Area = (width)x(height).  For 3-dimensions, I use Volume = (width)x(height)x(depth) or Volume = (length)x(height)x(depth) to avoid ambiguity.

(Of course there's nothing wrong with Volume = (length)x(width)x(height), but you can't be sure people will label the dimensions the same way.)

If I'm asked to draw a "2 by 4" rectangle, I'll probably draw it two units wide and 4 units tall (taking "2 by 4" to refer to the x- and y-measurements respectively).  But I think this is also ambiguous, and people may satisfy the request with a rectangle at any orientation.

Comment: I agree it's ambiguous, but because of the relationship between the words "length" and "long", I always assume "length" means the longest dimension. I think this is the most common usage in colloquial speech.

Comment: In the lumber industry, when specifying the cross-section, the smallest dimension is always given first, e.g. a two-by-four. Generically, one can speak of two-by lumber to include two-by-six, two-by-twelve, etc and form sentences such as 'I think we can make all of this out of two-bys' Matrices are always rows first. Trousers are always waist-by-leg. Having a convention saves time and/or space, within the expert community

Answer (score 3):

The Merriam-Webster dictionary defines **width** as *the measurement of the shortest or shorter side* of an object. Similarly that dictionary defines **length** as *the longer or longest dimension* of an object. It also defines **length** as *the longer or **vertical** dimension of a piece of a clothing*. Now this is just a bit of "tailoring", that it is common to use elbow-length for measuring the sleeves (vertical) of a shirt, and waist-width (horizontal) of trousers. (It is a different matter if someone's waist-width is more than their elbow length, which is quite possible)